# Apache RewriteRule Regex issue - rewriting url to point to external site

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have posted a similar question earlier that got answered and I believed it to solve this issue, but sadly it didn't.

I own two websites, where I am using one as a multisite WordPress site and the other as a site to redirect traffic from.

Updated .htaccess for secondary site:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?secondary.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://primary.com/secondary/$1 [P]
```

And this `.htaccess` on my primary site:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.(php|js|css|woff|ttf|svg))$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# END WordPress
AddType x-httpd-php54 .php
```

At first glance, it seems to be working fine, but there are two main issues:

1. All links on the site seem to be pointing towards **`http://secondary.com/secondary/article-title`** instead of **`http://secondary.com/article-title`** and when I click on one of them I get redirected to **`http://primary.com/secondary/article-title`**. I think there's something wrong with my RewriteRules, but I am uncertain of where - anyone have a clue?
2. The rewrite doesn't seem to work in IE11 on Windows 8 or Chrome on a mobile device - it redirects instead. How could this be? And how can I fix it?

I'm fairly sure this has an easy solution to someone who knows what he/she is doing, but personally I am rather clueless when it comes to Apache, so any help with it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `%{HTTP_HOST}` contains host name only, not scheme or slashes. `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?secondary\.com$ [NC]` also backslashes not needed in replace string (url). [P-flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p) im not sure needed there in rule.

Comment: I added part of your code to the secondary .htaccess - the (www\.) part seemed like a good idea, but it still has the same issues on the site.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^.*$ http://primary.com/secondary/$0 [R]` I think you mean `[R]`-flag there (ie external redirect), not `[P]` (request via proxy module).

Comment: I do want it to rewrite the URL, rather than redirecting the client though. Tricking the browser to make it look like it is on another site. I am exploring my options at the moment, looking into other solutions - such as using DNS records and WordPress Domain Mapping plugins.

Comment: Domains must point to the same IP and to the same document root. Then you can manage paths depending on http host header.